# Spring Boot Application - H2 Database (1.4.200) Array column, Hibernate mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm creating a Spring Boot application, where I have a **Routes table**. Within the Routes table I have **stops** column where I want to store the integer array of stop id.

Since H2 database (version 1.4.200) doesn't support typed array, I defined it as generic array.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Routes (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  stops ARRAY[100] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Routes (id, name, stops) VALUES (1, '500CK', (1,2));

SELECT * FROM Routes;
ID      NAME    STOPS  
1      500CK    [1, 2]
```

I want to know what should be the type of stops property (any other configuration required) so it works with Hibernate

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Routes")
public class Route {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    // I'm not sure what should be the data type of stops
    private Object[] stops;

}
```

I'm getting below **error while trying to get the route from /route endpoint**

```java
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "[1, 2]" [90004-200]
```

I created the Routes table by defining the DDL in the **schema.sql** file

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Routes;

CREATE TABLE Routes (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  stops ARRAY[100] NOT NULL
);
```

And I inserted one record by defining the DML in **data.sql** file

```sql
INSERT INTO ROUTES (id, name, stops) VALUES
  (1, '500CK', (1,2));
```

**UPDATE :**

I updated h2 to 2.1.212

```sql
CREATE TABLE Routes (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  stops INTEGER ARRAY[100] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ROUTES (id, name, stops) VALUES(1, '500CK', ARRAY[1, 2]);
```

I can see the above record in the Routes table.

Changed the Route entity as below

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Routes")
public class Route {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Integer[] stops;
  
    // getter & setters
}
```

I'm getting below error

```java
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "ARRAY to BINARY VARYING" [22018-212]
```

I'm using hibernate-core 5.6.8.Final

Looks like Hibernate is not able to do the conversion.

Can I achieve it with just Hibernate, Or do I have to do it, the way mentioned here

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

**Update : Trying to update hibernate-core to 6.1.0.Final**

I tried to update the hibernate-core to 6.1.0.Final.

```java
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But I'm getting below error

```java
Field routeRepository in net.mahtabalam.service.RouteService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

**Looks like this is caused due to dependency version conflicts.**

Below is the project **pom.xml**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.mahtabalam</groupId>
    <artifactId>routes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>routes</name>
    <description>Bus Routes</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.212</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use H2 1.4.200? This is and old unsupported version with many known bugs. Recent versions of H2 support standard-compliant typed arrays (`INTEGER ARRAY[100]` etc.) Hibernate ORM 6.1 should be able to map `Integer[]` properties to them. Old versions of Hibernate ORM need custom data type converters. You also need to use standard array literals (`ARRAY[1, 2]`), `(1, 2)`  is a syntax for H2 1.4.197 and older versions.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenijRyazanov, I updated the h2 to 2.1.212, but looks like Hibernate is not able to do the conversion properly.

Comment: Hibernate ORM 5.6.8.Final need custom converter, support for arrays was improved only in 6.1.0.Final.

Comment: I tried to update the hibernate-core to 6.1.0.Final, but looks like just updating the hibernate-core dependency is mismatching with other pulled dependencies by `spring-boot-starter-parent` and `spring-boot-data-jpa`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to my knowledge there will be no way to use hibernate 6.1.0.Final with Spring Boot currently. The issue you've noted with entityManagerFactory will be because the hibernate-entitymanager project was moved into hibernate-core in version 6.1.0.Final.

Looking through the plans for Spring Boot, [see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M3-Release-Notes), it looks like there is no imminment plan to update the version of hibernate used either as it won't be until M3 of version 3.

Instead your best bet will be to make a custom converter, I am currently trying to tackle the exact same problem and if I find a solution I will share it.